# how to add a C# string in javaScript as text popup

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Good day so here is my code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "messagebox", "<script>$(document).ready( function() { csscody.alert('<br/><h1>  Exception</h1><br/>The file that you have selected has Invalid/No matching Branch Code in our Database'"+Message+"',{onComplete: function(e){if(e){process();__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btndelete','');}}});return false;});</script>", false);
```

The problem is when i put the Variable Message inside the pop up doens't show (maybe its a syntax error) but when i remove it it shows as usall, so how would i add a text/String from C# to the code above? the Message variable contains this text

```
  String  Message = 123123 <br/> 22222 <br/> 1233 <br/> 33123 <br/>
```

Comment: You're closing your single quotes...

Comment: hahahahaahh @lc.that really sucks, post it as an answer :) ill mark it thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing your single quotes *before* you append the `Message` string. (Actually I think it's a stray single quote.) Try:

```
...anch Code in our Database" + Message + "'...
```

Comment: it works thank you :) ill accept it as soon as i can :) i also upvoted it hehe :)

Comment: @AsshO.Le No problem. Sometimes it just takes extra eyes.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "messagebox", "<script>$(document).ready( function() { csscody.alert('<br/><h1>  Exception</h1><br/>The file that you have selected has Invalid/No matching Branch Code in our Database\\''"+Message+"\\',{onComplete: function(e){if(e){process();__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btndelete','');}}});return false;});</script>", false);
```